# How to use another DNS Server when the PC is not in domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have two DNS servers (on DCs) in my domain that my clients use when they are connected direct in office or with VPN. I want to set up another external DNS server, and tell the PCs to use this server when they are not in domain. Is this possible via a script or GPO?

---

Thank you for the answer Emil, Esa is right, my Laptops are all already joined in a domain, i need a script to detect when the laptop is connected with the domain and when not. I have adapted your script to :

if ((Test-ComputerSecureChannel) -eq $true)
{

write-host -fore green "I am domain joined!"

} else {

write-host -fore red "Ooops, workgroup!"
}

but it doesen't always detect the domain, don't know why

---

Another idea that I have (don't know if it works, I didn't test it), is to configure all my clients with manual DNS Servers and:
by Primary - the DNS from my DC1; by secondary - the Extern DNS server. The problem here is, that I have to find a way that windows will switch from Prymary to secondary DNS immediately... I think the cache mode has to be deactivated on the client side.
What do you guys think? Should I try to find a script to detect when the pc is in domain or not, or try to use this solution?

Comment: Add more details on your environment, such as the DHCP setup. You have received two answers. Both are correct depending on how your network is setup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/463096/change-dns-with-script) describes the one-liners you would probably use for setting dns. Like this one:
Primary value:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.2
```

For actually doing this specifically to clients outside of domain, i would suggest trying to combine
netsh command with an if that checks for domain... which also is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409043/how-to-find-if-the-local-computer-is-in-a-domain):

```
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {
   write-host -fore green "I am domain joined!"
} else {
   write-host -fore red "Ooops, workgroup!"
}
```

Also you could run the script at startup so that the clients will check at boot.

Anyways, in my head your script could look something like this:

```
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {
   write-host -fore green "I am already joined"
} else {
   write-host -fore red "Not joined, using secondary dns"
   netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Local Area Connection" static <Ip-address>
}
```

(Most of our answers is from these forums, wonders :p)

Best of luck,
Emil

Comment: I don't think op is talking about domain/workgroup detection, but a moving domain computer (laptop).

Comment: Well, looking at it again now it is a bit unclear what the use-case is. But they are asking for a way to do this with GPO/script, so hopefully my answer can lend some direction. You are probably right, Esa.

Answer (score 1):

If they're configured as DHCP clients (which is the recommended configuration) then they'll be assigned whatever DNS servers the DHCP server assigns.

Comment: Hi, they are configured as DHCP clients, but when they are not connected to the domain, then they cannot reach the DHCP Servers

Comment: They can't reach your DHCP server, but they can reach any other DHCP server at whatever location they're at (home, school, hotel, coffee shop, etc., etc.), which is how people get internet/network connectivity when they're not in the corporate office. If that weren't the case, nobody could ever work except from their office.